# Dots on lemon tree leaves

Tags: pests, insects, citrus, flowering, lemons

The leaves on my lemon tree have these small yellow and brown dots. I assumed these are some kind of pests or insects and have therefore been spraying them with neem oil every 8 - 10 days. I even removed some highly affected leaves, but they keep reappearing. Any help with identification and resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: The top side of one affected leaf] | [image: The under side of another affected leaf] |

Also, I bought this grafted plant from a local nursery 4 months back and the seller told me that it would start flowering in a couple of months. I have been fertilising with bonemeal every 2 weeks, but no flowering yet. Any tips on getting the plnt to flower? Many thanks in advance.

PS: The plant is in a container on my balcony. I live in Mumbai, India.

Answer (score 1):

Texas A&M University has [a document here](https://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/citrus/l2315.htm) that you might want to read. If you look towards the bottom of the page there is a discussion of very similar symptoms related to Citrus Canker. Yes, I know that you are in India and this is a North American located research institution, but it might give you a start in your searches. Citrus canker is a serious disease so I hope you have something different, so check with your local agricultural authorities for the most local information.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the document. The symptoms of citrus canker do match the ones on my plant. I guess, I can now only hope to control it using fungicidal sprays or else get a new plant. Any suggestions whether neem oil spray would be the most effective? Or do I need chemical fungicides?